# How to set alternating colors for QTableView headers

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qtstylesheets, qheaderview

Using Qt 5.7.1 along and stylesheets, how can I make the row header section's background color, follow the same alternating pattern of the row cells?

My stylesheet is:

```css
QTableView {
   alternate-background-color: lightblue;
   background-color: grey;
}

QTableView::item:selected {
   background-color: lightgreen;
}

QTableView QTableCornerButton::section {
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 0px ;
}

QHeaderView {
   background-color: grey;
   alternate-background-color: lightblue;
}

QHeaderView::section {
   background-color: transparent;
   alternate-background-color: lightblue;
}
```

I've tried to enable it through:

```cpp
ui->tableWidget3->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
ui->tableWidget3->verticalHeader()->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this behavior not with qss but with subclassing of `QHeaderView`. For example:

```
#include <QHeaderView>

class AlterHeader : public QHeaderView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AlterHeader(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

protected:
    void paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const;
};

void AlterHeader::paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const
{
    Qt::Alignment align = (Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    if (logicalIndex % 2 > 0) {
        painter->fillRect(rect, QColor("lightblue"));
    } else {
        painter->fillRect(rect, QColor("grey"));
    }
    painter->drawText(rect, align, QString::number(logicalIndex));
}
```

And using:

```
AlterHeader *header = new AlterHeader(Qt::Vertical, ui->tableWidget);
ui->tableWidget->setVerticalHeader(header);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two improvements to [Serhiy Kulish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815642/17726418), again, overwriting QHeaderView, but alternatively using an overwritten QStyle:

```cpp
void AlternatingHeaderClass::paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const {
    QAbstractItemView* abstractView(qobject_cast<QAbstractItemView*>(parent()));
    if (abstractView && abstractView->alternatingRowColors()) {
        QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);
        if (visualIndex(logicalIndex) % 2) {
            painter->fillRect(rect, QColor(0, 0, 0, 30));
        }
    } else {
        QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);
    }
}
```

The advantage is, that it respects the settings of alternating rows of its parent and uses the `visualIndex`, so that it appears correctly on the screen. Disadvantage is, that also the text is fading out a bit. In addition, row selection might fail after this or needs to be added.

More properly, the effect could be achieved by defining a QStyle (as also already suggested) with the following method in it:

```cpp
void AlternatingHeaderStyle::drawControl(
        ControlElement element,
        const QStyleOption *option,
        QPainter *painter,
        const QWidget *widget
) const {
    painter->save();
    switch (element) {
        case CE_HeaderSection:
            {
                const QStyleOptionHeader *headerOptionPtr(qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionHeader *>(option));
                if (headerOptionPtr && (headerOptionPtr->orientation == Qt::Vertical)) {
                    QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);

                    QAbstractItemView* abstractView(qobject_cast<QAbstractItemView*>(widget->parent()));
                    if (abstractView && abstractView->alternatingRowColors()) {
                        const QHeaderView *verticalHeader(qobject_cast<const QHeaderView *>(widget));
                        if (verticalHeader && verticalHeader->visualIndex(headerOptionPtr->section) % 2) {
                            painter->fillRect(option->rect, QColor(0, 0, 0, 30));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
                }
            }

        default:
            QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
            break;
    }
    painter->restore();        
}
```